# How to monitor Flink Backpressure in Grafana with Prometheus metrics

Tags: apache-flink, grafana, prometheus, flink-streaming

Flink Web UI has a brilliant backpressure section. But I can not see any metrics, given by Prometheus reporter, which could be used to detect backpressure in the same way for a Grafana dashboard.

[image]
Is there some way to get the same metrics outside of the Flink Web UI? Using the metrics described here https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html. Or even having a prometheus scraper for scraping the web api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The back pressure monitoring that appears in the Flink dashboard isn't using the metrics system, so those values aren't available via a MetricsReporter. But you can access this info via the [REST api](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs-jobid-vertices-vertexid-backpressure) at

```
/jobs/:jobid/vertices/:vertexid/backpressure
```

While this back pressure detection mechanism is useful, it does have its limitations. It works by calling Thread.getStackTrace(), which is expensive, and some operators (such as AsyncFunction) do critical activities in threads that aren't being sampled.

Another way to investigate back pressure is to set this configuration option in flink-conf.yaml

```
taskmanager.network.detailed-metrics: true
```

and then you can look at the metrics measuring inbound/outbound network queue lengths.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Can you give some more info about the inbound/outbound network queue lengths? Assuming this is `inputQueueLength` the description is ` The number of queued input buffers.`. Which isn't very clear, is it the count of events which are in a internal buffer waiting for the consumer? Also is there an upper bound to how large this queue length can get? In other words, whilst I know that 0 internal buffer length means no back-pressure how do i know if it is high or low.

Comment: Except for sources, which don't have input buffers, and sinks, which don't have output buffers, you can look at both the input and output queues. How many events are in a buffer depends, as buffers are sent when they are full, or when the buffer timeout occurs, but there would typically be many events in one buffer. How much memory is available for network buffers is configurable, and how much is needed varies with the parallelism involved. You may need to experiment, and observe metrics like maxQueueLength. And you can probably get more insightful advice from the flink-user mailing list.